# Catalan number and Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, catalan-numbers

What is the number of sequences of positive integers, a1, a2, . . . , an, such that $a_1$ = 1 and
$a_{i+1}$ ≤ $a_i$ + 1 for any 1 ≤ i ≤ n − 1 ?

For example the five sequences, 111, 112, 121, 122, 123,
satisfy the condition.

(1). For $i>1$, we can have $a_i>1$. Then, we can have a bijective function.

(2). For $i>1$, we can have $a_i=1$. Then, the $a_1, ..., a_n$ can be broken into two parts.

I know (1) and (2) can form Catalan number, but I don't know how to form (1) and (2).

Comment: There's something wrong in $(2)$; you can't have $a_i=1$ for $a_i\gt1$.

Comment: Thank for the answer below. I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the least $k\gt0$ at which $a_{k+1}=1$, or $k=n$ if there is none. Then $(a_2-1,\ldots,a_k-1)$ is an admissible sequence of length $k-1$ and $(a_{k+1},\ldots,a_n)$ is an admissible sequence of length $n-k$. Conversely, concatenating any two admissible sequences whose lengths add to $n-1$, with the first sequence incremented by $1$ and a $1$ prepended, yields an admissible sequence of length $n$, and this mapping is bijective. Thus, if $C_n$ counts the number of admissible sequences of length $n$, we have

$$
C_n=\sum_{k=1}^nC_{k-1}C_{n-k}\;,
$$

which is the recurrence relation of the Catalan numbers. Also $C_0=1$ in agreement with the Catalan numbers, so the $C_n$ are in fact the Catalan numbers.

Comment: Still don't really get it. Say if $n=3$, then we have 111, 112, 121, 122, 123. Is it possible to give an example when it has bijection?

Comment: @user665125: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "an example when it has bijection". I proved that there's always a bijection, not just in certain examples. In your example, for $n=3$, we have

$$C_3=\sum_{k=1}^3C_{k-1}C_{3-k}=C_0C_2+C_1C_1+C_2C_0=1\cdot2+1\cdot1+2\cdot1=5\;,$$

corresponding to the bijection $111=1||11$, $112=1||12$ for $k=1$, $121=1|2|1$ for $k=2$ and $122=1|22|$, $1|23|$ for $k=3$. In each case, there's a $1$ before the first bar, a sequence of length $k-1$ incremented by $1$ between the bars, and a sequence of length $n-k$ after the last bar.